# Parsing Apollo GraphQL query into Sequelize query with include and attributes fields

Tags: javascript, recursion, graphql, sequelize.js, apollo

I'm working with Apollo, building resolvers for my GraphQL requests.

To be efficient I want to get a list of models requested (with respective nesting) and the fields requested from each of these models. That way I can pass this information to `sequelize` to only join the models when required - and only pull the fields necessary.

Resolvers do pass this information on in the `info` object.

```
(obj, args, { models }, info) => ...
```

From the `info` object the fields, nested models and their respective selected fields are exposed through this path:

```
info.fieldNodes[0].selectionSet.selections
```

My problem is parsing this structure (in some sort of recursive manner I imagine) into a sensible structure for me to pass into `sequelize` queries.

An example GraphQL query:

```
{
  getCompany(id: 1) {
    id
    name
    companyOffices {
      id
      users {
        id
        title
        userLinks {
          id
          linkUrl
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which generates the following on `info.fieldNodes[0].selectionSet.selections` (pruning some fields for the sake of brevity):

```
[
   {
      "kind":"Field",
      "name":{
         "kind":"Name",
         "value":"id"
      }
   },
   {
      "kind":"Field",
      "name":{
         "kind":"Name",
         "value":"name"
      }
   },
   {
      "kind":"Field",
      "name":{
         "kind":"Name",
         "value":"companyOffices"
      },
      "selectionSet":{
         "kind":"SelectionSet",
         "selections":[
            {
               "kind":"Field",
               "name":{
                  "kind":"Name",
                  "value":"id"
               }
            },
            {
               "kind":"Field",
               "name":{
                  "kind":"Name",
                  "value":"users"
               },
               "selectionSet":{
                  "kind":"SelectionSet",
                  "selections":[
                     {
                        "kind":"Field",
                        "name":{
                           "kind":"Name",
                           "value":"id"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "kind":"Field",
                        "name":{
                           "kind":"Name",
                           "value":"title"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "kind":"Field",
                        "name":{
                           "kind":"Name",
                           "value":"userLinks"
                        },
                        "selectionSet":{
                           "kind":"SelectionSet",
                           "selections":[
                              {
                                 "kind":"Field",
                                 "name":{
                                    "kind":"Name",
                                    "value":"id"
                                 }
                              },
                              {
                                 "kind":"Field",
                                 "name":{
                                    "kind":"Name",
                                    "value":"linkUrl"
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

Using this information I want to generate a query like the following:

```
  const company = await models.Company.findOne({
    where: { id: args.id },
    attributes: // DYNAMIC BASED ON QUERY
    include: // DYNAMIC BASED ON QUERY
  });
```

So I need to parse the GraphQL query above down to this something like this structure from the above `info` object:

```
{
  attributes: ["id", "name"],
  include: [
    {
      model: "companyOffices",
      attributes: ["id"],
      include: [
        {
          model: users,
          attributes: ["id", "title"],
          include: [{ model: "userLinks", attributes: ["id", "linkUrl"] }]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

But I'm unclear how to achieve this with recursion without things getting messy. If there's an easier way of achieving this dynamic `include`/`attributes` I'm open to that too.

**tl;dr - how can I transfer the models and fields of an Apollo GraphQL query into the `include` and `attributes` of a `sequelize` query?**

Answer (score 1):

It may be skirting the issue but I wonder if something like [graphql-sequelize](https://github.com/mickhansen/graphql-sequelize) could help with something like this. If not I've used [this strategy](https://medium.com/@vampiire/a-5-line-major-efficiency-hack-for-your-graphql-api-type-resolvers-b58438b62864#a693) to accomplish the attributes piece of your question.

```
const mapAttributes = (model, { fieldNodes }) => {
  // get the fields of the Model (columns of the table)
  const columns = new Set(Object.keys(model.rawAttributes));
  const requested_attributes = fieldNodes[0].selectionSet.selections
    .map(({ name: { value } }) => value);
  // filter the attributes against the columns
  return requested_attributes.filter(attribute => columns.has(attribute));
};
```

```
User: async (
    _, // instance (not used in Type resolver)
    { username, ... }, // arguments 
    { models: { User }, ... }, // context
    info,
  ) => {
    if (username) {  
      // (only requested columns queried)
      return User.findOne({
        where: { username },
        attributes: mapAttributes(User, info),
      });
    } ... 
  }
```

Comment: I read this article too - https://medium.freecodecamp.org/a-5-line-major-efficiency-hack-for-your-graphql-api-type-resolvers-b58438b62864 problem is that only covers the attributes for the top level of the query - not the nested models.

Comment: @BML91 you get a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a solution to this problem (kinda).

```
const mapAttributes = (projectors, models) => {
    const map = {};
    const set = [];
    Object.keys(projectors).forEach((projector) => {
        if (typeof projectors[projector] === 'object') {
            map[projector] = mapAttributes(projectors[projector], models.slice(1));
        } else {
            set.push(projector);
            map[models[0]] = set;
        }
    });
    return map;
};
```

here `projectors` is the object notation of graphql schema, same like the object we get from `info.fieldNodes[0].selectionSet.selections`

and models, is the orderly way of iteration. so in the example above it'll be like

`['company', 'companyOffices', 'users']` etc.

From the final map we get into a neat structure from which we good get the attributes.

And finally when you are returning the argument, you may need to convert the sequelize output into graphql type

```
const sequelizeToGraphql = (results = [], vouchers = [], postings = []) => {
    const final = { particulars: [] };
    results.forEach((result) => {
        vouchers.forEach((voucher) => {
            final[voucher] = result[voucher];
        });
        const obj = {};
        postings.forEach((posting) => {
            obj[posting] = result[`posting.${posting}`];
        });
        final.particulars.push(obj);
    });
    return final;
};
```

Here `vouchers` and `postings` are the table name for me in my sequqlize, similarly make changes for yourself